Was told in an interview that I could email them for more information, didn't get a reply
I had an interview the other week. It was the third and final interview for the position. The entire interview focused on cultural fit. In it, I spoke with the CEO. He said that there were 10 principles that the company has that are really important for all employees to follow. I asked what they were. He said to ask anyone I've been in correspondence with by email. I did and got no reply. Was it silly to ask? He seemed like he was sincere about their importance, should I follow up once more? For context, there has been a single email address I have been replying to but different people from the company have been using it.

"He said that there were 10 principles that the company has that are really important for all employees to follow. ... He seemed like he was sincere about their importance"   but he couldn't tell you what they were?  I would not like to work for that man.

A company that has 10 principles is a company I would conclude isn’t serious about all of their principles. Move on this isn’t a company you want to deal with.

@Donald there seemed to be a few red flags like this. Another was in each of the 3 interviews they told me the meeting had been scheduled at a time that wasn't good for them. I'm surprised they have such good reviews on glassdoor.

@kebabclang, some companies may ask their own employees to write good reviews about the companies on Glassdoor and other websites. (There is no way to verify which reviews are authentic or not).

@Grasper "he is referring to the 10 commandments" and "they might be a Christian company" are indicating two very different levels of confidence. There's also decidedly more than just one list of 10 principles. People like round numbers. There's no reason to assume that this is referring to the biblical commandments.

Update: they got back to me and said they will send a job offer. The CEO said someone was on vacation and that's why no one responded to my email. The 10 principles are things like "be on time" and "own your work".


Was it silly to ask?

No. You can email HR or recruiters to ask again.

However, if the CEO did not even briefly highlight some of these 10 principles to you during the interview, it probably means that he does not really care very much about these 10 principles.
Furthermore, you already emailed and asked their employees about these 10 principles, and got no reply. Again, it probably means that they don't care about these principles either.
In reality, many companies have lots of meaningless slogans and principles, which serve no practical purposes and therefore, no employees in the companies really care about these (Yeah, not even the CEO cares).

I have worked for a company that has had several sets of guiding principles over the years. Nothing wrong with that, though it may or may not affect day today operation. Few of us could quote the complete sets accurately offhand, though we might know some.
But any interviewer who cites something of this sort without being able to immediately explain it is, at best, not a very good interviewer. Of course, if interviewing isn't in their actual job description, this may not be surprising. Interviews, unfortunately, are often an afterthought in company procedures, and are often administered by people who do not know the best practices.
So I wouldn't get hung up on this issue. If you like what you've been able to find out about the company, and like what you've been able to find out about the job, then when and if you're offered the position you can consider taking it. If something struck you as fishy, forget it and move on to the next company. If they don't say they want to hire you, put it aside and move on to the next company. Remember that you are interviewing them as much as they are interviewing you, and don't get hung up on any one opportunity until you have a signed offer, with salary and starting date, in hand.

No
Your time would be better spent finding a serious company that could use you.
Update: My point is silly (yes - silly) games about 10 principles, along with 3 interviews on top of no response. How can that be considered a company that is serious, and is serious about hiring you? That behavior is odd at best. The CEO propagating this behavior is enough of a red flag to be very concerned.

The CEO is out of touch with reality.  There probably isn't an employee who can tell you what more than 3 of them are unless they read off the script and its likely most employees can't name a single one.
He seems like the kind of guy who would yell at the employee for taking the time to reply to you, after asking you to email them.
The clear indication of this is 10 principles.  They probably contradict each other which is bad, but worse is that most of us can only concentrate on three things at time.  Ten is impossible.  Five occasionally for some.
So if you take this job, despite all the fanfare, it will only be an average job.  If the pay is good and it works for your lifestyle then take it.  Just don't believe their crap.
